# Как организовать хранение настроек QSettings в формате info?

Tags: boost, qt, c++

Из документации я знаю, что нужно переопределить 2 функции чтения и записи.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/info_parser.hpp>

const QSettings::Format ConfFormat = QSettings::registerFormat ("conf",  read, write);
QSettings m_storage = new QSettings(ConfFormat, QSettings::UserScope,  
                                              organizationName (),applicationName ());

bool read(QIODevice &device, QSettings::SettingsMap &map) {       
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    QFile *file = qobject_cast<QFile *>(&device);

    boost::property_tree::info_parser::read_info(file->fileName ().toStdString (), pt);

    for(pt::const_iterator it = pt.begin (); it != pt.end (); ++it) {
        // как организовать тут доступ к элементам?
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Вот вариант решения на SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656380/boost-1-46-1-property-tree-how-to-iterate-through-ptree-receiving-sub-ptrees

Comment: Хотелось бы без BOOST_FOREACH обойтись, чтобы код был чище.

Comment: Так если вы используете библиотеку BOOST, то почему бы не использовать и BOOST_FOREACH? Ведь это приведет к уменьшению вашего самописного кода и облегчит чтение программы.

Comment: Не хотелось бы слишком толстый бинарник, ведь BOOST_FOREACH это просто надстройка над итераторами. Так зачем всё усложнять, есть можно использовать итераторы? Хотя если без BOOST_FOREACH не обойтись, придётся его использовать. И ёще. Автокомплит в креаторе не вставляет после first\second метод data().